# Powershell 4 XML node access notation puzzle

Tags: xml, powershell

Powershell 4  windows Server 2008 R2

So recently I wrote a Powershell script to dial into the app pools of my machine web configuration file for IIS. I really don't know the name of the way this access the XML nodes, but here is how it was done the first time:

```
$appPoolNode = ($config['configuration']['system.applicationHost']['applicationPools']['add'] | where {$_.name -eq $AppPoolName})
```

Sadly this did not work with anything but the default app pool.
So if I wanted to change something for another app pool that was made, I could not get anything to return from the above line of code. I pulled in a co-worker who showed me the dot-notation of accessing XML nodes:

```
$appPoolNode = ($config.configuration.'system.applicationHost'.applicationPools.add | where {$_.name -eq $AppPoolName})
```

And somehow this code works.

My question is:
what kind of XML access is the 1st code sample code called, and why does dot-notation work for other app pools instead of just the defaultappPool   like the first code sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fun with PowerShell magic :-)

Your `$config` variable is of some type derived from `System.Xml.XmlNode`. PowerShell does this when you cast some string to `[xml]`.

This type includes among other methods a property `Item`, which like in C# is used to handle the accessor syntax with the brackets, so writing

```
$config['a']
```

gets resolved into a function call

```
$config.Item('a')
```

which returns a single value - the first child node matching the given name.

Now, if you use the `.` notation for this, you just invoke another property, but in this case one added dynamically by PowerShell when it parsed the XML file.

It adds a property for each child node name and each attribute it finds on the current node. If there is more than one child node with a given name, it makes the property return the *array* of these nodes and that is where it differs from the Item method, which returns only the first value.

To see this with a simple example, consider

```
$x = [xml]"<a> <b Id='1'/> <b Id='2'/> </a>"
```

Then `$x | Get-Member` shows the usual `XmlDocument` properties, including `Item`, plus a property `a` which returns a single XmlElement. So at this point

```
$x['a']
$x.Item('a')
$x.a
```

all return the same. Now do `$x.a | Get-Member`. You see that `Item` still returns a single XmlElement, but since b occurs more than once in the XML, PowerShell lets the `b` property return an array of generic objects (which happen to be of type XmlElement again).

Consequently

```
$x.a.b
```

gives you both `Id` values, while

```
 $x.a['b']
```

only returns the first one.

Comment: Nice explanation, @TToni :)